# Changing Application Insights Logging Level at Runtime on Azure App Service

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have deployed an application as a Microsoft Azure Web App with a log level Default of Information as shown below in appsettings.json in code. Is it possible to change the log level for example to Trace during runtime without redeploying?

"ApplicationInsights": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft": "Warning",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}

Comment: Using kudu to modify app.setting, and it doesn't need to restarting the web app instance or re-deploying : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using kudu?

First, we all know that we can [change the log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson) by modify the configuration in appsetting.json, hence we can using kudu to change the value after deploying to azure web app. Pls note the setting in my screenshot below, it's `Logging->appinsights->loglevel`

After deploying to azure web app, you can visit `https://yourdomain.scm.azurewebsites.net` to reach kudu website, in this website, you can modify all the settings in static files. I've tested in my side and it worked well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tiny Wang, KUDU indeed works. I went one extra step to restart the application service for the corresponding logs to start appearing. Thanks

Comment: If you feel my post is helpful, could you pls accept it as the answer (click the  √ )? Many thanks : )

Comment: TIny Wang. answer marked as Accepted. Thanks

Comment: So actually you didn't change them during runtime... Because you need to restart the application in order to take into effect..

Comment: I'm not very sure if this still worked now because it already passed 1 year. At that time, the changes take effect after I changed the configuration without a restart. Have you test  it now? It doesn't work any more without a restarting? @MaartenKieft